# Employee Salary Should display monthwise as moth displaying Horizontally as Headings

Tags: postgresql, jasper-reports, pivot, crosstab

My requirement is as follows:
Am using Postgresql and ireport 4.0.1 for generating this report.
I've four tables like g_employee,g_year,g_period,g_salary, by joining these four tables and passing parameter are fromDate and toDate these parameter values like '01/02/14' between '01/05/14'.Based this parameters the displaying months will be vary in the headings as i shown in the below example:

EmpName

```
       01/02/14     01/03/14    01/04/14    01/05/14
  abc   
            2000            3000    3000    2000
```

Can anyone help me in this getting output?

Answer (score 1):

What you're describing sounds like the number of columns would grow or shrink based on the number of months between the 2 parameters, **which just doesn't work**.

I don't know any way to add **additional columns** based on an interval between 2 parameters without a procedural code generated sql statement.

What is possible is:

```
emp_id1  period1 salary
emp_id1  period2 salary
emp_id1  period3 salary
epd_id1  period4 salary
emp_id2  period1 salary
emp_id2  period2 salary
emp_id2  period3 salary
epd_id2  period4 salary
```

generated with something like:

```
select g_employee_id,
       g_period_start,
       g_salary_amt
  from g_employee, g_year, g_period, g_salary
 where <join everything>
   and g_period_start between date_param_1 and date_param_2
  group by g_employee_id, g_period_start;
```

Hard to get more specific with out the table structure.
As the range between date_param_1 and date_param_2 grew, the number of rows would grow for each employee with pay in that "g_period"

EDIT - Other option:
The less dynamic option which requires more parameters would be:

```
select g_employee_id,
       (select g_salary_amount
          from g_period, g_salary
         where g_period_id = g_salary_period_id
           and g_salard_emp_id = g_employee_id
           and g_period_start = <DATE_PARAM_1> ) as "DATE_PARAM_1_desc",
       (select g_salary_amount
          from g_period, g_salary
         where g_period_id = g_salary_period_id
           and g_salard_emp_id = g_employee_id
           and g_period_start = <DATE_PARAM_2> ) as "DATE_PARAM_2_desc",
       (select g_salary_amount
          from g_period, g_salary
         where g_period_id = g_salary_period_id
           and g_salard_emp_id = g_employee_id
           and g_period_start = <DATE_PARAM_3> ) as "DATE_PARAM_3_desc"
        ,..... -- dynamic not possible
   from employee;
```

Comment: Thank you for response but i don't need output like that. My requirement is periods should display horizontally and and salaries also for corresponding emp's.Can anyone help me please..

Comment: Thats just not how SQL works. The number of columns is a constant for any valid SQL statement.

Comment: You need something to model the data the way you wish, either procedural code or a modeling application that will take what i've provided and display it the request way. The other option is not dynamic based on the input range, (you have to add or remove colums manually as the range changes). I'll show that example.

Answer (score 0):

i create one table #g_employee and insert dummy data

```
create table #g_employee(empid int,yearid int,periodid int,salary int)
insert into #g_employee(empid,yearid,periodid,salary)
select 1,2014,02,2000
union
select 2,2014,02,2000
union
select 3,2014,02,2000
union
select 3,2014,03,2000
union
select 1,2014,03,3000
union
select 1,2014,04,4000
```

output query as per your requirement :

Solution 1 :

```
select empid, max(Case when periodid=2 and yearid=2014 then salary end) as '01/02/2014'
, max(Case when periodid=3 and yearid=2014 then salary end) as '01/03/2014'
, max(Case when periodid=4 and yearid=2014 then salary end) as '01/04/2014'
from #g_employee
group by empid
```

you can do with dynamic sql :

Solution 2 :

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(periodid) 
                    from #g_employee
                    group by periodid

            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = 'SELECT empid,' + @cols + ' from 
             (
                select salary, periodid,empid
                from #g_employee
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(salary)
                for periodid in (' + @cols + ')
            ) p '

execute(@query)
```

hope this will help